# How to ignore TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep in unit tests

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, powermockito

I have a method which is calling sleep of 30 seconds but I dont want my unit test to have the same. I want my unit test to ignore the sleep and execute the rest on the method or reduce the sleep time to 1 sec.

```
public runwithSleep(){
 System.out.println("Before Sleep Time");
 TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(30);
 System.out.println("After Sleep Time");
}
```

From the above sample code, How do I ignore the `TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(30)` when executing the **unit test** for this method. Basically I want to test like if i can reach this method from a condition so I dont want the sleep in the test.

Comment: Don't use sleep in the first place

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To complement the previous answer from @Michael Gantman, currently above:

3. Replace the dependencies to the sleep method with a dependency to a Sleeper object that you will inject. In the unit tests, you'll inject a Sleeper that does not wait. Bonus: the tests can interrogate the Sleeper to check if it was called, and with which parameter.

Comment: Very nice idea. +1 to you

Answer (score 4):

1. extract your business logic into separate method and call it after
   sleep from your original method. This way in your unit test you can
   just test your extracted method that does not include sleep.
2. Make a sleep value as a parameter instead of hardcoded value, and in your test you can set it to a small value while for regular runtime keep it to 30 sec.

Answer (score 0):

The idea from @philant is really nice, if you can modify your source code, that is the choice to make your life easier. TimeUnit is an `enumeration` class and SECONDS is one of its `static final` fields, which makes it more safe but hard to mock at the same time.

If you have to mock `TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep` for any reason, the only solution I know is using `reflection`, but remember, "use magic only when science fails."

The good news is that PowerMock provides packaged tool `Whitebox` and mock with PowerMock is easy:

```
TimeUnit timeUnit = PowerMockito.mock(TimeUnit.class);
Whitebox.setInternalState(TimeUnit.class, "SECONDS", timeUnit);
Whitebox.setInternalState(timeUnit, "milliRatio", 1000);
PowerMockito.doNothing().when(timeUnit).sleep(anyLong());
```

However, if PowerMock is abandoned from your project, you have to do all the tricky things wrapped in Whitebox all by yourself.

```
Method getDeclaredFields0 = Class.class.getDeclaredMethod("getDeclaredFields0", boolean.class);
getDeclaredFields0.setAccessible(true);
Field[] fields = (Field[]) getDeclaredFields0.invoke(Field.class, false);
Field modifyerField =
    Arrays.stream(fields).filter(it -> "modifiers".equals(it.getName())).findFirst().orElse(null);
modifyerField.setAccessible(true);

TimeUnit timeUnit = Mockito.mock(TimeUnit.class);
Field secondsField = ReflectionUtils.findField(TimeUnit.class, "SECONDS");
secondsField.setAccessible(true);
modifyerField.setInt(secondsField, secondsField.getModifiers() & ~Modifier.FINAL);
ReflectionUtils.setField(secondsField, TimeUnit.class, timeUnit);

Field milliRatioField = ReflectionUtils.findField(TimeUnit.class, "milliRatio");
milliRatioField.setAccessible(true);
milliRatioField.set(timeUnit, 1000);

Mockito.doNothing().when(timeUnit).sleep(Mockito.anyLong());
```